# Custom listView design doesn't work on device, but works in emulator

Tags: android, motodev-studio

Here's the code:

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, 
                R.layout.zalistu, 
                android.R.id.text1, 
                values);
```

So this is the adapter, where I made my own design for the list (`R.layout.zalistu`) and this work in the emulator, but on the device it gives me an error (the application had stopped unexpectedly) If I use the `simple_list_item_1` then it works correctly both on emulator and my device.

Here is R:layout.zalistu:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FF00FF"
/>
```

The LogCat:

```
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1495)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:843)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1892)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     ... 32 more
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x2
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1978)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:350)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:343)
08-13 13:26:15.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6832):     ... 35 more
```

Android version on my device is 2.3.7, version on emulator is 4.0.4 (API 15)

Answer (score 3):

All the attributes from R.attr you've used, such as [listPreferredItemPaddingLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#listPreferredItemPaddingLeft), are only available as of Android 14 ( ICS ) where your device is gingerbread. Solution : set it manually, try a few values until one seems right. Either that or set the minSDK accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps a better solution would be to copy the resource file in question to `res/values-14`, and omitting it from the version in `res/values`. This will retain the behavior in ICS, whereas you can provide alternative padding for pre-ICS.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`android:id="@+id/text1"`** instead of  **`android:id="@android:id/text1"`**

and also...

**`adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.zalistu,R.id.text1,values);`**

Comment: unfortunately still no change

Comment: `@android:id/text1` should be fine.