# Android App Crashes on HTC and Sony Ericsson Phone

Tags: android, crash-reports, sony, htc-android

We launched the app on the Market today - [Nomad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.m7.nomad). I am getting reports that the app crashes on HTC and Sony Ericsson Phones. I got the following Log report from one of the USER.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.m7.nomad/com.m7.nomad.SplashActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x3
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x3
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5459)
at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1776)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1700)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:741)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2707)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2767)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:247)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
at com.m7.nomad.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:46)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
... 11 more
```

Not able to understand why it happens.

SplashActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;

    // Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    // Shared Preferences
    settings = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFS, 0);

    configRun = settings.getInt("database_version", 0);

    this.assetManager = this.getAssets();


}
```

Line 46 points to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);`

**activity_splash.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_color" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="Splash Screen"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You might want to share some code... Especially the part that crashed. Otherwise the most sensible thing we could say is: 'You have a bug'

Comment: It's seems something wrong with layout of your `SplashActivity`. Please post your layout's `xml` and code from `com.m7.nomad.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:46)` line 46 of you activity

Comment: @Veger have added the code :)

Comment: @Evos have shared the code of the Activity as well

Comment: Do you really sure you need this 2 tags for your relative layout :`android:textAlignment="center"` `android:gravity="center"`. Could you try to remove them?

Comment: @Evos yes. i had other content so had used it. guess i can remove them now.

Comment: @Evos i think i will need  gravity = center since the image has to be displayed at the center

Comment: Possible duplicate @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146057/android-eclipse-using-string-resource-for-text-size-in-layouts

Comment: @AndersMetnik i am not using any dimension here. so any idea how it can be solved ?

Comment: Try after removing the orientation of the relative layout...

Comment: @Harsha M V till this is a relative layout gravity tag don't works there so you can safely remove it. What about second `textAlignement` tag?

Comment: @Evos yesh i removed that :D thanks i will test it :D

Comment: @AndroidLearner oh okay. i will remove it too :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your splash layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffe5492a"
android:contentDescription="Splash Screen"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:src="@drawable/splash_logo" >
```

Comment: why cant i use a layout ? i need to fill a background color

Comment: you can use `android:background="@color/primary_color"` if you like, BTW same color. :)

Comment: any idea why it is happening ??? i mean why does it happen only on HTC. i dont have a htc at my disposal. getting it checked from a friend :D

Comment: I guess `android:textAlignment="center"` is buggy on HTC devices, just a guess.... ;)

Comment: Here is a hint, launch your AboutActivity or MainActivity instead of SplashActivity. If it still crashes then the problem is with your theme, remove this tag `android:theme="@style/Theme.Nomad"` from your manifest and it will surely work. If it works then you will know where to look.

Comment: I was right :P Problem is here `<item name="android:layout_marginStart">@drawable/ic_menu_share</item>` in your theme. ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23204/discussion-between-m-wajeeh-and-harsha-m-v)

Answer (score 2):

The cause of your crash is likely tucked away in your styles. It likely contains an attribute referencing a dimension contained within the Android SDK, whereas you are running your application on an older version of the SDK that does not contain that dimension.

[In this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933392/custom-listview-design-doesnt-work-on-device-but-works-in-emulator), the author used the following attribute:

```
android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
```

However, as the accepted answer points out, the [`listPreferredItemPaddingLeft` entry](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#listPreferredItemPaddingLeft) in `android.R.attr` is only available from SDK level 14 onwards.

Either remove the offending entries, replace them, or separate the resource files such that they respect the SDK level. For instance, you could provide one style in `res/values-14`, and another omitting those entries from the version in `res/values`.

Comment: removing them just worked fine and didnt change anything so we have done that for now. thanks for pointing out how to accommodate the same using value-14. i will try that and let you know :D

Answer (score 1):

Apply this xml in your project and see what happens :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:textAlignment="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="Splash Screen"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment this line ::

```
context = this;
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: damn dont have a htc phone.. getting it tested :P will report back :D

Comment: have you set the same package name in the manifest ?share more code of the splash activity and xml files.

Comment: can i mail it to you so that i dont have to share the file in public ?

Comment: i dont find ur email id :D